# Trying to change content within a div with tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to create a tab bar that upon a click selection changes the content within the div, I have attached a jfiddle link here:

http://jsfiddle.net/v1cgqvpw/

```
$(function () {
$.fn.showField = function () {
    var selectVal = document.getElementById(this.val() + 'Div');
    return this.each(function () {
        $(selectVal).show().siblings('div1').hide();
    });
};
$('select#reportsSelect').change(function () {
    $(this).showField();
});
```

When clicked i would like it to be highlighted whilst the other 2 remain their colour unless hovered over or clicked. And upon being clicked as per above to change the content within the box, it's confusing my brain at the moment and all help is appreciated...hopefully it's as simple as it sounds!

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

`this` is a DOM element, which has no method `.val()`. That is a jQuery method. You need to use either `this.value` or `$(this).val()`. That also applies for the `.each` method.